# Understanding datetime conversion

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, datetime-format

In PHP, the `date()` function can be used as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE memberJoined between '".date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')."' AND '".date('Y-m-d 11:55:55')."'
```

In C#, the formated datetime I set up for members in my DB is `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS`, e.g `3/12/2013 12:27:06 AM`

I would like to create a similar query in C# as I would like to pick up only the row satisfying a specific datetime range. I prefer using `DateTime.Compare()` though.

Comment: are your columns a datetime?

Comment: please don't store datetime as string....

Comment: Yes, sure, a column to store datetime when the member joined. I mean also the column type is `datetime?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a parameterized query with DateTime values:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE memberJoined between @startDate AND @endDate";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql);
SqlParameter startParam = command.Parameters.Add("@startDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
startParameter.Value = //Some date time object
SqlParameter endParam = command.Parameters.Add("@startDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
endParameter.Value = //Some date time object
```